# How to view details repeatedly in magento grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I have two tables.

1. **table_return**
2. **table_return_history**

I am getting data from **table_return**  to the **grid**.
I want to view the history details from **table_return_history** by the **return_id**.

I tried to get the details like this.

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{   
    //-- new Form --
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'          => 'edit_form',
        'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save',array('return_id'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('return_id'))),
        'method'    => 'post',
        'enctype'   => 'multipart/form-data'
    ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('edit_form',array('legend'=>Mage::helper('requestreturn')->__('Packages Information')));

    $return_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_id');
    $return_model = Mage::getModel('requestreturn/requestreturnhistry')->load($return_id);

    $fieldset->addField('product_name','text',array(
        'label'      => Mage::helper('requestreturn')->__('Return Ref :'),
        'name'       => 'product_name',
        'value'      => $return_model->getProductName()
    ));
```

But if the history table has two product it want show in history page.

How can i get repeat data if available?

**UPDATE**

Without form method is there any way to show the history details in page?

Comment: what will you get in `$return_model` ?? Product IDs??

Comment: yes i can get product ids

Comment: So you want to display product name comma separated in GRID like Product A, Product B